# How to save BLOB to SQL-Server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, blob

I'm able to upload an image file and using PHP's `file_get_contents` put the binary into memory. From there I've attempted to use a basic `update` or `insert` query statement to then put that data into a blob. It keeps throwing errors. 
In addition I've tried to use the `addslashes` PHP function as well, and it still doesn't work. 
I've tried:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'])){
        $fileData = file_get_contents($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']);
        $fileData = unpack("H*hex",$fileData);
        $content = "0x" . $fileData['hex'];
    }
```

Then I try to `insert` into my database and it doesn't work either. 
The datatype for my BLOB field is `image`.

The error I am most often getting is:
`mssql_query(): message: Operand type clash: text is incompatible with image (severity 16)`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This seems to do something similar: [18944368/php-pdo-load-image-into-ms-sql-server-2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944368/php-pdo-load-image-into-ms-sql-server-2012).