# how to upload binary image to sql server using php laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, file-upload

As far as I know, uploading images to databases is wrong, but in this specific issue, I have to upload images to `SQL Server`. I found some results, for example using the `base64` string.
My database structure contains a lot of images with type of `image` in `SQL Server`.
Since I'm unfamiliar with SQL server, I'm using Laravel 5.4 for connecting to databases.

The problem now is this.

> How can I upload an image to SQL Server(colomn type: `binary image`) using php in laravel?

What is the best way to display this image?

Comment: Answer should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944368/php-pdo-load-image-into-ms-sql-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image to a temp location then read it into a var with file_get_contents() then insert it into your database column (needs to be binary blob or something similar). To display it you can use a route like this:

```
Route::get('images/{id}', function($id)
{
    $image = Images::find($id);
    $image = Response::make($image->content, 200);
    $image->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    return $image;
});
```

This assumes you are using Eloquent for dealing with your DB.

Tested this using help from here:
https://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2014-how-do-you-save-image-to-database-and-display-it-on-website

Answer (score 0):

My answer is bit messy, as Eloquent doesn't support Image BLOB to SQL Server, so the concept is we treat the image as param to SQLSrv driver based on [PHP PDO load image into MS SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944368/php-pdo-load-image-into-ms-sql-server-2012) , then we can upload it using bare PDO SQLSrv using BindParam.

example

```php
Route::post("/example", function(Request $request) {
    /** @var \PDO $db */
    $db = DB::connection("sqlsrv")->getPdo();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO gambar VALUES(:id, :gambar)");
    $stmt->bindValue("id", $request->input("angka"), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $gambar = $request->file("gambar")->getContent();
    $stmt->bindParam("gambar", $gambar,
    PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);
    // $stmt->bindValue("gambar", $request->file("gambar")->getContent(),
    // PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    dd($stmt->execute());

});
```

It's quite messy, as I can't use the built in Eloquent ORM, sad... noises...